# StreamInsight Service on Windows doesn't recognize the application dlls

Tags: c#, dll, complex-event-processing, streaminsight

I have my project worked fine with embbed stream insight instance.
But when I tried to use the standardalone StreamInsight service on Windows, I got an exception when this code is run

```
using (matchQuery.Bind(sink).Run())
```

An exception of type `'Microsoft.ComplexEventProcessing.ConnectionException' occurred in Microsoft.ComplexEventProcessing.Diagnostics.dll`

It said that `The management service encountered an error: Could not load file or assembly 'MyApplication, Version=1.0.5198.16312, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.`

**My question**

**1.** Why doesn't StreamInsight recognize the dlls?

**2.** Do I need to installing the dlls to GAC?

Im using StreamInsight 2.1

My system is 64 bit.

My project is configurated with any CPU.

Answer (score 1):

Put your dlls to the debug folder and restart the windows service.